# What causes RegionResize errors for maps of specific countries?

Tags: bugs, regions, polygons

I want to resize the map of the country as below.

```
region = EntityValue[Entity["Country", "SouthKorea"], "Polygon"] /. g_GeoPosition :> g["LongitudeLatitude"]
newregion = RegionResize[region, 10]
```

However, newregion often stops with no results.
Also, all previously executed information will be erased.
This works mostly well for other countries. However, errors often occur in SouthKorea.

What causes RegionResize errors for maps of specific countries?

Comment: please report the bug to WRI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I tried your example with "SchematicPolygon". Use separate cells for each of the following commands, if possible. I am showing the output of the last command.

```
region = EntityValue[Entity["Country", "SouthKorea"], 
   "SchematicPolygon"] /. g_GeoPosition :> g["LongitudeLatitude"]

RegionPlot[region]

newregion = RegionResize[region, 10]

RegionPlot[newregion]

RegionPlot[{region, newregion}]
```

[image]

#### Wierd behavior

Then I switched various other countries and notebook wouldn't evaluate properly and plot two different countries one on top of the other, unable to reassign `region`. Evaluation->Quit Kernel->Local was grayed out. So I terminated Mma and restarted.
This time I used yet another country, and it remembered the last country. (persistence).
Then I tried "SouthKorea" but this time with "Polygon". The image below shows that it can be done.

Obviously, this is strange behavior. I am on Mma 12.2 Win7-x64 8GB. It takes less than 5 seconds to do these calculations.

[image]

Comment: thank you. Helped a lot!!